# Sending SOAP request to WCF from a not .NET client

Tags: wcf, soap, authorization, token

I have a **WCF webservice** that works correctly if I call it from a **WPF client application**, which is not in the same machine nor in the same domain. The **app.config** of the client application is:

```
 <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" closeTimeout="00:05:00"
          openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="1524288000"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="1524288000" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000" maxStringContentLength="819200" maxArrayLength="163840" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://my.service.com/MyService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService"
        contract="LicenseService.IMyService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
    </client>
```

After calling the WCF service I sniff with **fiddler** the SOAP envelope, I modify the timestamp, I copy/paste the content in the client, for instance Chrome Postman, I send the request to the WCF and I receive an error. Below there the SOAP request envelope and the given error, which is too generic and I cannot find a good solution anywhere. My best guess is that it has something to do with the way WPF handles the security tokens but I cannot find what's wrong. The token can be used just once? Anybody might help?

**Error message:**

> *The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be
>   because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between
>   sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender
>   and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same
>   contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g.
>   Message, Transport, None).*

**SOAP envelope:**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2014-10-24T09:39:11.198Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2014-10-24T09:44:11.198Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <o:UsernameToken u:Id="token">
        <o:Username>MyUsername</o:Username>
        <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</o:Password>
      </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetProduct xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <productGuid>productGuid</productGuid>
    </GetProduct>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

The WCF service used CustomValidation with WS-Security. The client didn't support the WS-Security therefore it couldn't process the header of the SOAP message. Morevoer in the client the WS token was not refreshed and it was already been consumed by the WCF service